# Difficult to watch vs difficult in watching

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

> I know Argentina is a great team but I am sure even Argentina fans found it **difficult to watch** their defenders defend yesterday.

Vs

> I know Argentina is a great team but I am sure even Argentina fans found it **difficult in watching** their defenders defend yesterday.

Is difficult + gerund form correct? Or should difficult always be followed by infinitives?

Comment: The expression “find something difficult” is generally followed by the infinitive form. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=found+it+difficult%2C+find+it+difficult+&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfound%20it%20difficult%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfind%20it%20difficult%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Alternatively you may use “have a difficult time” + gerund. “Argentina fans had a difficult time watching thier defenders...” or “had difficulty watching..”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[difficult (for somebody) (to do something)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/difficult) not easy; needing effort or skill to do or to understand.

> It's difficult for them to get here much before seven.
>   It's really difficult to read your writing.
>   Your writing is really difficult to read.
>   ***She finds it very difficult to get up early.***

(OLD)

The idiomatic expression “*have a difficult time or have difficulty*” are followed by the gerund form.